# JBoss EAP 7.0.5 can not add https-listener

Tags: jboss, wildfly-10

I am adding a new security realm and https-listener with CLI:

```
/core-service=management/security-realm=HTTPSRealm/:add

/core-service=management/security-realm=HTTPSRealm/server-identity=ssl:add(alias=ssl,keystore-path="/path/to/configuration/testCA.jks", keystore-password="12345678")

reload

/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https:add(socket-binding="proxy-https", security-realm="HTTPSRealm")
```

At the last step I only get this:

```
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => undefined,
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

I already tried every solution I could find here. (running as batch etc)

**Edit:**

The listener config is added like this:

```
/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/socket-binding=proxy-http:add(port=9080)
/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/socket-binding=proxy-https:add(port=9443)
```

Comment: Is there anything in the `server.log`?

Comment: I have set the log levels to debug and there still is nothing more in the log.

Comment: Do you know which command is failing?

Comment: First two commands succeed. Last commands fail.

Comment: What does the configuration for your `proxy-https` socket binding look like?

Answer (score 0):

Have you created socket bindings for `proxy-https` ? The default binding is `https`. Try with it

> /subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https:add(socket-binding=https, security-realm=HTTPSRealm)

Comment: The socket binding works, but adding the https listener fails.